# Selection Filtering By Another Selection

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I'm looking for a way to filter subsequent selections depending on which ones of them are filled.
I want to have a tree-like structure for setting locations as such:

=>Country

==>State

===> District

So say you enter the district first, you'd only have one choice in the other two.
Say you enter the country first, you'd have a more limited selection of the latter two.

I know i should be going with many2one fields but all i can get working at this point is multiple selections that turn visible/invisible which is highly inefficient.

I'm fairly new to Odoo and am finding the docs somewhat lacking. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi. You made a `python` tag, and it doesn't appear to be related. Consider removing it.

Comment: @Aryerez Done, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would play around with `many2one` fields and domains using the operator `=?`

For example:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = "my.model"

    country_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="res.country")
    state_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="res.country.state")
    disctrict_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="res.country.state.district")
```

I don't know if the model names are correct, but you should already know them.

And in the view use the domain with the mentioned operator:

```xml
<field name="country_id"
    domain="[('state_ids', '=?', state_id),('state_ids.district_ids', '=?', district_id)]" />
<field name="state_id"
    domain="[('country_id', '=?', country_id),('district_ids', '=?', district_id)]" />
<field name="disctrict_id"
    domain="[('state_id', '=?', state_id),('state_ids.country_id', '=?', country_id)]" />
```

I didn't make any tests on those AND conditions/domains. And i don't know the structure of those 3 models. My assumption is, that there is a `one2many` or `many2many` relation on `res.country` -> `res.country.state` and `res.country.state` -> `res.country.state.district`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you elaborate a bit on how the domains work?

Comment: If there is `False` (empty) value on the right in the domain expression, it will actually return "True". So for example if you have set a `state_id` in the client, the field `country_id`'s domain will be like `[('state_ids', '=', state_id), True]` or bit more understandable `only show countries my chosen state is part of AND true`. So these domains work like when one part isn't set, they just ignore it.

Comment: i only just discovered that syntax is outdated, what version do you develop on?

Comment: For real? i really loved that operator. Haven't done so much for V12

Comment: Nope it's even in the 12 doc: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#domains and i found one example in module account

Comment: that's weird, plugging it into a Studio code thingy changes it to a "?" and changes it if you touch it and putting it in a view ... well i cant get any views to work

Comment: Studio is a thing for itself. The whole editor changing things and auto formatting code sucks hell... Have you tried using Settings/technical/views to change the view? Or is it the same?

Comment: i've used it to move around fields that the studio locks in place by default. Starting to think i shouldn't touch it cause it's giving me bad habbits. I'm obviously new to Odoo development

Comment: I personally would only use it for mockups. The produced code is a pain in the ass...